# How to calculate price average while grouping by date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5.7 I need to calculate the average discount per merchant and day.

There are 2 tables:

produts_manufacturers:

```
PROD_ID | MANUFACTURER_ID | PRICE_RECOM
1         1                 10
2         1                 20
```

merchants_prices

```
PROD_ID | MERCHANT_ID | PRICE_ACTUAL | DATE
1        10            9.00           21-01-20
1        11            8.80           21-01-20
1        11            9.00           22-01-19
```

My goal is a chart that gets its metric value from  `group by DATE, merchant_id`

Now how is it possible to calculate the average discount of all products from a manufacturer at a particular merchant without also grouping by PROD_ID?

```
   SELECT
        date,
        merchant_id,
        1- (t.PRICE_ACTUAL / p.PRICE_RECOM)*100 AS discount2
        -- (1 - ROUND(AVG(PRICE_ACTUAL),2) / p.PRICE_RECOM)*100 AS discount
    FROM
        merchants_prices t
        INNER JOIN produts_manufacturers p ON t.PROD_ID = p.PROD_ID
    WHERE
          p.MANUFACTURER_ID = 1
        AND PRICE_ACTUAL IS NOT NULL
    GROUP by
        date,
        MERCHANT_ID
    ORDER BY
       date desc,  merchant_id
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate average discount per merchant and day:

```
SELECT `DATE`, MERCHANT_ID, ROUND(AVG(discount), 2) as discount
FROM (
  SELECT mp.`DATE`, mp.MERCHANT_ID, 1- (mp.PRICE_ACTUAL / pm.PRICE_RECOM)*100 AS discount
  FROM produts_manufacturers pm
  JOIN merchants_prices mp ON mp.PROD_ID = pm.PROD_ID
  -- WHERE pm.MANUFACTURER_ID = 1 -- If you want to restrict to a specific manufacturer
) as x
GROUP BY `DATE`, MERCHANT_ID;
```

With your dataset ->

```
DATE           MERCHANT_ID  discount
2021-01-20     10           -89
2021-01-20     11           -87
2022-01-19     11           -89
```

To help you I made a [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddec1031b2f49b4578a1e437b654bfb5)